# How to resolve "trust anchor for certification path not found." in Xamarin Project?

Tags: android, r, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

i am new to Xamarin Forms/mobileDev and im trying to create a simple application that consumes data from an API.

I'm using the following tutorial to do that [Consuming an Web API ASP.NET Core](http://www.macoratti.net/18/03/xf_apilvgrp2.htm) but as i try to connect to my API i get the following error message:

> Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException  Message=java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

My webAPI is working fine so i assume the problem is on my mobile app.

I read some posts here in StackOverflow but i couldnt find one that solve my problem as i found all the answers to be a little complex for my level of mobile developing.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this link, some additional steps need to be done in order to consume local web service and to handle certificate security check
[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check)